# Spymemcached client auto-reconnect to another server in Couchbase Cluster?

Tags: couchbase, spymemcached

I read Couchbase Rebalancing document (http://blog.couchbase.com/rebalancing-couchbase-part-i) and it wrote : "A client losing its connection to the cluster will attempt to reestablish (configurable). Anytime it reconnects (first time or not) it gets the latest map that the cluster has. Ironically, a flaky network in theory might just help here to keep the map constantly updated during a rebalance, but that's for a different discussion."

I use Spymemcached 2.7.3 and how can i achieve that.

I give an example: My Java client add two server (10.0.0.40 and 10.0.0.15, use URL) to connect to Couchbase cluster. But in reality, when 10.0.0.40 down, the persistent connection did not keep. I have to restart my client to switch to 10.0.0.15. How can my client can re-connect to 10.0.0.15 when 10.0.0.40 down without restart my application.

Updated:

I use below code to connect to Couchbase cluster:

```
        ArrayList<URI> listAddr = new ArrayList<>();
            listAddr.add(new URI("http://10.0.0.40:8091/pools"));
            listAddr.add(new URI("http://10.0.0.15:8091/pools"));
                listAddr.add(new URI("http://10.0.0.16:8091/pools"));
            client = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(), listAddr, "test", "test", "");
```

I want to my java client auto reconnect to another server in pool (40,15,16) to get topology (when my java client's still running) if the first server in pool (40) failed.

Can i achieve this purpose with spymemcahce or i have to move to Couchbase Java SDK.

Comment: The Couchbase Java Client is based on the spymemcached project and folks from Couchbase, Inc. maintain/contribute to spymemcached.  You'll find that there are a number of updates past 2.7.3 for automatically recovering in these kinds of scenarios.

You don't say what behavior you get say from logs or the like, so it's hard to say for certain that one of the later versions address the problem.

What do you get logging wise?

Comment: i already updated the question

Answer (score 1):

spymemcached java client dos not handle membase fail over for particular node.

You can check [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/handling-memcached-failover/) .

If you update your java client to couchbase java client, then you can handle fail over by removing  failed node from cluster.
for more information you can check [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-client-dont-connect-another-cluster-node-when-first-is-down/10573) or [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/node-failure-blocks-java-client/3421/12)